# Username/Password Authentication Failed. dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege

Tags: ppa, dpkg, authentication, launchpad

```
gichan02@gichan02-Latitude-D520:~$ wget https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu/pool/main‌​/x/xojo/xojo-bin_2013.41-0ubuntu1_i386.deb; dpkg -i xojo-bin*.deb
--2014-05-28 00:17:18--  https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu/pool/main%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/x/xojo/xojo-bin_2013.41-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
Resolving private-ppa.launchpad.net (private-ppa.launchpad.net)... 91.189.95.83
Connecting to private-ppa.launchpad.net (private-ppa.launchpad.net)|91.189.95.83|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
--2014-05-28 00:17:20--  https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu/pool/main%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/x/xojo/xojo-bin_2013.41-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
Reusing existing connection to private-ppa.launchpad.net:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

Comment: You have two problmes. First it apperars you do not have access to the repositories "401 Authorization Required". Second, you have to run dpkg as root, "sudo dpkg -i xojo-bin*.deb"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated You are trying to connect to a private repository. The server is requesting authentication but failing w/401 error (Personally tested). You do not have authentication from the server.

In addition, you are trying to run 2 commands back to back:

`wget https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu/pool/main‌​/x/xojo/xojo-bin_2013.41-0ubuntu1_i386.deb; dpkg -i xojo-bin*.deb`

to back, hence `;` which is the separator.

You are running `dpkg -i xojo-bin*.deb` this must be ran as sudo `sudo dpkg -i xojo-bin*.deb`

Alternatively, You can simply download the package from https://www.xojo.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Now I got Xojo App running Finally. I Logged into Launchpad and went to
https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xojo/

Then I downloaded .deb file and installed.

The only thing that I am worried about now is the 'Updates'.

But all in all I can use xojo.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark. In the future please do not edit the title as (SOLVED)

Comment: Oh.That's how it works...thank you very much for the information.